# How to tell if my Java component is in an Applet?

Tags: java, applet

I have a Component which I am using both in a standalone Java application as well as in a Java applet. How can I figure out from within the Component whether my component is in an applet?

Also, once I figure out that I'm running in an Applet, how can I get access to the Applet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to do it by repeatedly calling `Component.getParent()` until you get to the top of the container tree, and then checking whether that container is an `instanceof Applet`.

The code below is completely untested:

```
boolean isInAnApplet(Component c)
{
    Component p = c.getParent();
    if (p != null) {
         return isInAnApplet(p);
    } else {
         return (c instanceof Applet);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it without recursion by [SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getAncestorOfClass(java.lang.Class,%20java.awt.Component))

Comment: There is also SwingUtilities.getRoot.